# Deprecation of Link Local IP Flag?

Tags: docker

The Docker CLI supports --link-local-ip on the run and network connect commands for IPV4 and IPV6 addresses. Disregarding IPV6 (which I don’t have a strong grasp on at the moment), I’m curious about the fact that the recent (v3+) versions of the docker-compose schema have decided to abandon support for link-local-ip. I’ve also noticed that you can create a docker network with the 169.254/16 addresses that are reserved for link-local.

I’m curious what the use-case is for the separate link-local-ip flag, why it’s not seemingly important to docker-compose, and any opinions on what it’s future might be (maybe link-local doesn’t make a bunch of sense in a Swarm/Overlay network world?)